# c#: Please explain FillRectangle() coordinates?

Tags: c#, graphics

Could you please explain coordinates in `FillRectangle()`? I understand that `x,y` are upper-left corner of rectangle? But in this case:
[small picture 1](http://img207.imageshack.us/img207/319/99653477.png)

I understand `x`. But `y is = 627`, which is even > than main window's height (`137`). Still, somehow this works as it supposed to:
[small picture 2](http://img337.imageshack.us/img337/6900/66904029.png)
(we're talking about red rectangle here).

I just completely don't understand this `y` coordinate.

Thanks.

Comment: Did MSDN not help you? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6ksfcek.aspx

Comment: "Don't understand Y coordinate" - I am not sure what is your actual problem here - are you talking maths here or a specific problem?

Comment: The y coordinate of this small red rectangle is 627 while the height of gray painting area is 137. That's what I don't understand. To my understanding y coordinate should be about ~15?

Comment: Seems like bug in the code. Please share more code. Need to check where is this `graphics` object coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gray box's height is only 137 pixels, but its position on the parent form or container is 510 pixels down.

The coordinates in use here aren't relative to the gray box, they're relative to the parent container. This is why you're seeing numbers that are larger than the size of the box.

Comment: Excellent! That seems to be exactly the "issue" for me.
Thank you very much!